# Sql select for complex classes

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have a problem with making a select statement for situation with List inside an object.

Let's say that i have classes that look like this:

```
public Class Role {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
public Class User {
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

of course getters and setters are there too.

I'm working with project where i need to use JdbcTemplate for querying objects from database and we dont have ORM.

So here is a question: Is it possible to make such SQL Select statement that no mapper will be used for that outside the automapper for JDBC template?

I can do something like this in java code:

```
List<User> users = sqlManager.createQuery("SELECT login, password FROM users", 
                                          User.class).getResultList();
```

But i want also a result from roles table for that users to be automapped to list of users.

btw that is only example, im working with much more complex object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB design will consist of two main tables representing the `user` and `role` and a helper table representing the `m:n` relation between them.

```
create table  User_tab (
    login varchar2(100),
    password_hash raw(100), 
    CONSTRAINT User_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (login)
);

create table Role_tab (
    id Int,
    name varchar2(100),
    CONSTRAINT Role_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
); 

create table User_Role_tab (
    login varchar2(100),
    id Int,
    CONSTRAINT User_Role_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (login,id),
    CONSTRAINT User_Tab_fk FOREIGN KEY (login) REFERENCES User_tab(login),
    CONSTRAINT Role_tab_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Role_tab(id)    
);
```

So to get the list of roles for a specific user you will use this query

```
select id from User_Role_tab where login = ?
```

Note that you are correct in identifying the problem in missing `ORM`.

But note also that with your approach you actualy tries to **reimplement an ORM with all the problems that it tries to solve or cause**. Check e.g. `n+1 select` problem.

So you should make some initial evaluation if your apprach is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for help, that "n+1 select problem" is exaclty what i was looking for.